# Lorentz transformation length contraction contradiction

Tags: special-relativity

[image]

We have a rod moving at relativistic speed. If $l_0$ is the actual length from the rods perspective. $ x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are positions of ends of the rod from the perspective of the rod.
I get a result that says that the length is longer from earth's(non moving) reference frame, when I know it should be smaller.

I know you can derive the correct formula the other way around(from earth's perspective), but I wanna know why does this not work when I should be able to do it both ways and get the correct anwser(both perspectives equaly valid, hence relativity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your derivation you forgot to transform the time coordinate. You have found the distance (in the unprimed frame) between two events that do not occur at the same time. Thus $l$ does not actually represent a length.

Comment: But doesn't measuring the length have to happen at the same time. I mean I need to measure the position of the left end and the right end at the exact same time(in both frames of reference). No? Why not?

Comment: You are forgetting the relativity of simultaneity. It can’t be simultaneous in both frames. The events you transformed are simultaneous in the primed frame, not the unprimed frame. So they can represent a length in the primed frame only.

Comment: Ok thank you so much man.

Comment: You are welcome!